# Is there some special attribute to ornate a property of a class to deserialize inclusive nested properties of an object from XML?

Tags: arrays, xml, serialization, nested, xsd

I have to get the data from an XML file to an object. I have already do this for a simple class, but for one with nested children as array of elements I've not receiving the values from enumeration, only from main part.
Is there something special to do in order to get the nested items?

I have an xsd file from a third part company with the structure of the xml file. They are also sending me the xml files on that structure.

I've created my vb.net class using xsd.exe from Visual Studio. The class is big enough to be hard done manually.

I don't know how to get all data from my xml using deserializing method. If I use an dataset, I get all data, but it is very hard to convert the dataset to my object.

How can I deserialize all nested objects?

Here are the elements. You can download [the files at GoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vdpOTmmg1FHnAaWt4XtWq_CFSouxO5tp?usp=sharing).

1. The XSD files: **PathDetailsMessage.xsd**, **Common_Elements.xsd**
2. The class generated: **PathDetailsMessage.vb**
3. The XML file: **OneTrain.XML**
4. My code:

   ```
   Dim obj As PathDetailsMessage
   Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(GetType(PathDetailsMessage))
   Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fullPath)
     obj = CType(ser.Deserialize(reader), PathDetailsMessage)
   End Using
   ```
5. The properties with abnormal null (nothing) values.

   ```
   obj.PathInformation
   obj.CFRTrainInfo
   ```

I have to use something like this:

```
For Each pjl As PlannedJourneyLocation In obj.PathInformation.PlannedJourneyLocation
  ''                          
Next
```

but `obj.PathInformation` is nothing!

Comment: What version of `xsd.exe` did you use to generate the code?

Comment: When I use `xsd.exe` that shipped with VS2022 to generate VB code for the same XSD files I get very different code - you may be using the wrong version of `xsd.exe`. In my code, the `obj.PathInformation` and `obj.CFRTrainInfo` properties are properly populating.

Comment: @mamift XSD.exe from visual studio 22 Version 4.8.3928.0

Comment: In that case, what is the exact **xsd.exe** command that you are running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think the issue is that you're running an extra `xsd.exe` command that is unnecessary to generate your code. The only command required is:

`xsd .\PathDetailMessage.xsd /l:VB /c /namespace:infofer`

Here's an example of my working code where `obj.PathInformation` and `obj.CFRTrainInfo` are not null, and properly populated (run the *[ConsoleTest](https://github.com/mamift/SO_76532514/tree/master/src/ConsoleTest)* project to see for yourself):

https://github.com/mamift/SO_76532514/tree/master/src/lib/OneTrain

I can see in your provided code you've run `xsd.exe` twice on both schemas, and then manually edited the generated code in **PathDetailsMessage.vb** to remove it from the `infofer` namespace, which resolved build errors you would've gotten regarding duplicate declarations. You'll also notice you've got classes like `AdministrativeContactInformation` declared twice, once in PathDetailsMessage.vb and agin in Common_Elements.vb.

If you take a look at **PathDetailsMessage.xsd**, there's this include directive on line 3:

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="Common_Elements.xsd"/>
```

Because **Common_Elements.xsd** is included by the **PathDetailsMessage.xsd** file, xsd.exe is smart enough to import those elements and generate code for that file alongside **PathDetailMessage.xsd**. It's just that the tool **does not** split the generated code into a separate **Common_Elements.vb** file.

Comment: Thank you very much, @mamift! Yes, I used a command for PathDetailMessage and another one for Common_Elements

Comment: @Tratak if I answered your question, can you mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: Sure. Sorry for delay !

Comment: I have 4 xsd files with Common_elements.xsd in coomon. I've created 4 classes but I/ve put a different namespace for each class, to not interfer with the common part. Now it works fine